# make query more simplest and in one query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

How to make this query more simplest and in one query?

Problem - only topics has a meta_key 'include_newsletter_feed'
So i need get all posts ("product", "post", "page") excluding categories (124, 52)
And join all topics with meta.

Example ugly code

```
$arg =  array(
        "post_type" => array("product", "post", "page"),
        "posts_per_page" => 3,
        'category__not_in' => array( 124 /*Gallery*/, 52 /* Discounts */ )
    );
$_posts = get_posts($arg);
$arg =  array(
        "post_type" => "topic",
        "posts_per_page" => $nimbus_posts_on_home,
        'meta_key' => 'include_newsletter_feed',
        'meta_value' => 'true',
    );
$_topicts = get_posts($arg);
$_all_posts = array_merge ($_topicts, $_posts);
$ids = array();
foreach($_all_posts as $_post) {
        $ids[] = $_post->ID;
    }
/* Final query */
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array( "post_type" => array("product", "post", "page", "topic"), "post__in" => $ids ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works only with filters
'posts_groupby', 'posts_where' and 'posts_join'.
Please write if you know better solution.

```
$args =  array(
    "post_type" => array("product", "post", "page", "topic"),
    "posts_per_page" => $nimbus_posts_on_home,
    'category__not_in' => array( 124 /*Gallery*/, 52 /* Discounts */ ),
);
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'recent_posts_widget_groupby' );
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'recent_posts_widget_where', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'recent_posts_widget_join', 10, 1 );  

function recent_posts_widget_groupby( $groupby ) {
    remove_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'recent_posts_widget_groupby' );
    if( strpos($groupby, 'wp_posts.ID' ) === false )
        $groupby .= " wp_posts.ID ";
    return $groupby;
}

function recent_posts_widget_join( $join ){
    remove_filter( 'posts_join', 'recent_posts_widget_join' );
    $join .= " INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
     INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) ";
    return $join;
}

function recent_posts_widget_where( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'recent_posts_widget_where' );
    $post_types = array();
    foreach( $wp_query->query['post_type'] as $post_type) {
        if( $post_type != 'topic')
            $post_types[] = $post_type;
    }
    $post_type_in = implode("','", $post_types );

    $where = " AND( 
      wp_posts.post_type IN ( '$post_type_in' )
      OR 
      ( 
        wp_posts.post_type='topic' AND( mt1.meta_key = 'include_newsletter_feed' AND mt1.meta_value = 'true' )
      )
    ) ". $where;
    return $where;
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So final SQL query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 

 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  WHERE 1=1  AND( 

  wp_posts.post_type IN ( 'post','page','product' )
  OR 
  ( 
    wp_posts.post_type='topic' AND( mt1.meta_key = 'include_newsletter_feed' AND mt1.meta_value = 'true' )
  )

)  AND ( 
wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
            SELECT object_id
            FROM wp_term_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (164,142)
        )
) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'topic', 'product') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'closed')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php 

    $args=  array(
            "post_type" => array("product", "post", "page"), 
             "cat" => '-124,-52', 
             "meta_query" => array(
               array(
                "key"     => 'include_newsletter_feed',
                'value'   => "",
                'compare' => '!='
                   ),
              ),

         ); 
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't working.

Comment: Query also must contains post_type 'topic' with meta_key 'include_newsletter_feed'

Comment: Try the edited solution. I changed the compare value and that does work for me in a similar query

Comment: It's not return anything.
After adding a "post_type" => array("product", "post", "page", **"topic"**) it's return only topics